# How to make text that is outside of the header/footer to repeat for every page in Odoo Qweb report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I need a custom text to repeat on every page in multi page pdf report. The thing is that this custom text is not in the header/footer section. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Why don't you move it to the header or footer?

Comment: Because it is vertical text that takes the whole right side of the report.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<template id="report_test">
<t t-call="report.external_layout">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <div class="page">
            <!-- Add text you want to repeat every page here -->
            <div class="row"> 
                <!-- your reprot data print here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: This code will show a page for every object but will not repeat particular text on every page for the same object. For example if you have invoice with 20 lines in it, that are three pages, the text will be shown on the first page and on other two pages will be shown only header, footer and table.